# How do I call the 'popoverControllerDidDismissPopover' method?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I am having trouble calling the the `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover` method in as much as I do not know where to put it and how to call it.

I have created a popover as follows -

```
//  SettingsViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SharedData.h"
#import "PlayerPopUpVC.h"

@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UIPopoverControllerDelegate> {

- (IBAction)popUp:(id)sender;


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *playerPopUpVC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) PlayerPopUpVC *popUp;




//  SettingsViewController.m
#import "SettingsViewController.h"



- (IBAction)popUp:(id)sender {

    UIButton *editPlayers = (UIButton *)sender;

    if(self.playerPopUpVC) {

        self.popUp= [[PlayerPopUpVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayerPopUpVC" bundle:nil];

        self.popUp=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.popUp];

    }

    [self.playerPopUpVC presentPopoverFromRect:[editPlayers frame] inView:[editPlayers superview] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; 

}
```

I know I have to set the delegate of my PopOver to self in order to call the method but cannot work out what the code is.

I have tried -

```
self.playerPopUpVC.delegate=self
```

but Xcode does not like it.

My popOver class looks like this -

```
//  PlayerPopUpVC.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PlayerPopUpVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UIPopoverControllerDelegate> {


}


//  PlayerPopUpVC.m

#import "PlayerPopUpVC.h"

@interface PlayerPopUpVC ()

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.modalInPopover = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(240, 400);
}
```

Any help would be most welcome. I have spent a week now trying to sort it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand the delegate pattern, which seems that you dont fully understand yet.

The popover will be the one which will call the `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover` method on the delegate. You only have to implement the `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` protocol in your class and assign yourself as the delegate of the popover. Why do you say that XCode doesn't like it? please, provide more info.

Furthermore, you are making an incorrect assignment here:

> ```
> self.popUp=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.popUp];
> ```

**Edit: Provided more code to help with the error. Please, review the delegate pattern next time before making these questions.**

Your SettingsController.m should have this instead:

```
- (IBAction)popUp:(id)sender {

    UIButton *editPlayers = (UIButton *)sender;

    if(!self.popUp) {

        self.popUp= [[PlayerPopUpVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayerPopUpVC" bundle:nil];
    }

    self.playerPopUpVC=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.popUp];            
    self.playerPopUpVC.delegate = self;
    [self.playerPopUpVC presentPopoverFromRect:[editPlayers frame] inView:[editPlayers superview] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; 

}
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
   // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Hi Angel, thank you for your quick reply. I have now added the popover  class. Yes I know I have to tell the delegate to use the dismiss method. So does the dimiss method go into the delegate class .m then? Also, you say I have incorrectly assigned the above self.popUp. I am creating the popup outside the popup class within the popup method I have created. As such it will only let me refer to the PlayerPopVC & popUp as .self. Any thoughts? Thanks Paulh

Comment: I updated my answer. Check it out and please read how the delegate pattern works because you haven't understand it yet.

Comment: And you dont need to implement UIPopoverControllerDelegate in your PlayerPopUpVC because it is not the delegate of the popover!

Comment: Hi Angel, Thank you you're a star. It works. The code I was using was based on an example from a book I bought from my local bookshop. I will study your code against the one I used to see what the diference was. I am spending the rest of the day studying delegates. I best way I learn is by reverse engineering working code to understand it. Thanks again. Paulh